# Cant overwrite the custom stylesheet

Tags: css, reactjs, rangeslider

I am trying to overwrite the CSS of react range slider.It uses the custom style sheet of which i need to add in the head section.My project is built on next.js

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-rangeslider/umd/rangeslider.min.css" />
```

Otherwise, the slider doesn't show anything if i don't add the link in head even though I installed the library. It's not even overwriting the CSS. I want  to change the background color.This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import 'react-rangeslider/lib/index.css';
import './slider.css';
import Slider from 'react-rangeslider'
class Horizontal extends Component {
    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context)
        this.state = {
            value: 850
        }
    }
    handleChangeStart = () => {
        console.log('Change event started')
    };
    handleChange = value => {
        this.setState({
            value: value
        })
    };

    handleChangeComplete = () => {
        console.log('Change event completed')
    };
    render () {
        const { value } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='slider'  style={{ marginTop:'165px',marginLeft:'319px',width:'700px',backgroundColor:'EF5350'}} >

                    <div style={{ textAlign:'center',color:'gray',fontSize:'35px',marginBottom:'82px'}}>
                        <p> What is the size of your property?</p>
                    </div>
                    <Slider
                        min={850}
                        max={5000}
                        value={value}
                        onChangeStart={this.handleChangeStart}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
                    />
                    <div className='value'>{value}</div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Horizontal
```

I tried to change the background color in slider.css.

```
.rangeslider-horizontal .rangeslider__fill {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The library needs to be installed first:

```
npm install react-rangeslider --save
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work as the slider stylesheet overwrite yours. Include the style like

```
// To include the default styles
import 'react-rangeslider/lib/index.css'
// import your css
import './style.css';
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qtffad)

Comment: No maybe i have some problem with react Dom.I am new in react maybe it will take some time figure this out.after copying your code  I am getting this error   `"Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError):`     document is not defined' .

Comment: you need to import your css, below `import 'react-rangeslider/lib/index.css'`

Comment: i checked in console.it still uses custom css  the link i used.I have imported the library too

Comment: did you remove the css link?

Comment: After removing it shows nothing.It's not getting the css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193960/discussion-between-junius-l-and-ariful-islam).

Answer (score 1):

always make your own CSS stylesheet file the last file to import after any other CSS stylesheet files to make overwrite you need
otherwise, you can always use the console in the browser to auto-detect any error by pressing F12 in the browser then go to the tab called (console)

I think you can style element you want to live in the console to know the detail of how to nesting element

you also can open the CSS file in the editor and press Ctrl+F then find the line of code you want to style then copy its property and value to your own CSS file and then you can edit it so easy